# Magento 2: I want to show shipping address from quote address table on payment page

Tags: magento2

I want to show shipping address from quote address table. Currently there is showing default shipping address.

[Please Check screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJS1A.png)

Please help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please see the following pages to help you get the most out of StackOverflow and the community; [What topics can I ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  If you need further assistance please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

I also have to show default billing address set by customer on checkout as label only.